# How can I get jQuery $('.class', context) to include context itself if it matches .class?

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors

I want to be able to match against all elements in a given context *including* the context element itself.
Here is the code I'm using currently, but it seems inefficient. Is there a better way?
Note: I'm using jQ 1.3.2, but I'll upgrade soon so I'm interested in 1.4 solutions too.

```
var context = $('#id');   
var filters = '.class1, .class2';

// take context itself if it matches filters
$(context).filter(filters)
// add anything matching filters inside context
.add($(filters, context))
```

Note: `.add($(f,c))` works in jQ 1.3 as `.add(f,c)` in jQ 1.4

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do this:

```
$(context).find('*').andSelf().filter(filters)
```

[.andSelf()](http://api.jquery.com/andSelf/) appends the previous element on the stack, in this case the context.  But...I'm not sure this is really any better than your current approach, with the filtering it's a bit slower.  I think you've just hit a situation that doesn't look pretty, would be nice if `.andSelf()` took a selector, then you could do:

```
$(context).find(filters).andSelf(filters)
```

Still not a huge improvement though.

Answer (score 2):

Looks like @Nick Craver's idea got pushed to production. jQuery's [addBack()](http://api.jquery.com/addBack/) function has replaced `andSelf()` and it accepts a selector.

```
$(context).find(filters).addBack(filters)
```